# How to flex boxes when I shrink the tab

Tags: html, css

I want it to align the boxes top to bottom with like 2 rows or 3 rows that depends on the size of the tab I already tried to do but I couldn't do it with current situation with the flex structures/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 , maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
 

<section id ="blog">

<div class="blog-heading"></div>
<h3><span>En Yeniler</span></h3>
<h1>Staj Gelişmeleri</h1>


<div class="blog-container">

<div class="blog-box">

    <div class="blog-img">

        <img src="/Fotolar/Software-Development-Life-Cycle.png" alt="XXXXX">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-text">
            <span> SDLC Nedir ve Ne İşe Yarar</span>
            <a href="/Fotolar/laptop html -css.jpg" class="blog-title "></a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex accusamus porro, eius totam repellendus quas recusandae rem, minimadeserunt sint ad nihil debitis obcaecati assumenda nemo vitae tempore cum hic.</p>
      <div class="border" id="renk">
            <a  id="linkler" target="_blank" href="/Sekmeler/SDLC.html"> Sayfaya Git </a>
     </div> 
    </div>
        </div>
  
  
    </div>
    
        


    <div class="blog-box">

        <div class="blog-img">
    
            <img src="/Fotolar/CICD.png" alt="XXXXX">
                </div>
                <div class="blog-text">
                <span>CI/CD Gelişirme süreci Hakkında Bilgiler </span>
                <a href="html-css.jpg" class="blog-title"></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex accusamus porro, eius totam repellendus quas recusandae rem, minima, deserunt sint ad nihil debitis obcaecati assumenda nemo vitae tempore cum hic.</p>
                <div class="border" id="renk">
                <a  id="linkler" href="#">Sayfaya Git</a>
          </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    
        
        <div class="blog-box">

            <div class="blog-img">
        
                <img src="/Fotolar/software-724x394.webp" alt="XXXXX">
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-text">
                    <span>Web Geliştirme Projem   </span>
                    <a href="laptop html -css.jpg" class="blog-title "></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex accusamus porro, eius totam repellendus quas recusandae rem, minima, deserunt sint ad nihil debitis obcaecati assumenda nemo vitae tempore cum hic.</p>
                    <div class="border" id="renk">
                <a id="linkler" href="#" target="_blank"> Sayfaya git </a>
              </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        

</section>  
</body>
</html>
```

```css
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-family:poppins;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #c0a5ab

}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: poppins;
}
#blog{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0,0.05);
}
.blog-heading{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.blog-heading span{
    color:#f33c3c;

}
.blog-heading h3{
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.blog.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.blog-box{
    width:500px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border:4px solid #ecececec;
    margin: 50px;
 
    
}
.blog-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
.blog-img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;

}

.blog-text{
        padding: 40px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
}
.blog-test span{
     color: #f33c3c;
     font-size: 0.9rem;

}
.blog-text .blog-title{
font-size:  1.3rem;
font-weight: 500;
color: #272727;
}
.blog-text .blog-title:hover{
    color: #130707;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    }
    .blog-text p{
        color: #2f1e55;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        display:-webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        margin:20px 0px;
    }
    .blog-text{
        color: #da5252;
    }
    .blog-text a:hover{
        color: #f33c3c;
        transition: all ease 0.3s;
    }

    @media(max-width:1250px){
        .blog-bog{
            width: 300px;

        }
    }
    @media(max-width:1100px){
.blog-box{
    width: 900%;
    
}

    }
    @media(max-width:500px){
        .blog-box{
            margin: 20px 10px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

#blog{
padding: 20px;
}
#blog{
    color: rgb(53, 53, 41);
}

#renk{
 border-width: 3px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color:rgb(196, 141, 141);
 color:#7e0404
}

.border{
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: #bd9099
}
#linkler{
color: #5f574d;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-weight :bolder;
background-color: #bd9099
}
```

I manage the to convert the boxes to flex but when I shrink the tab it still doesn't move I want it to align all boxes [like this xd it doesn't matter if its 2 or 3 rows I just want to learn how to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsKxx.png)